# Fixed point of maps between product of even dim projective spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems, projective-space

Is this true ? :

> There exist a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}P^{2n} \times \mathbb{R}P^{2m}$ to itself with no fixed
> point. Here n, m ≥ 1.

I know (by an exercise in Hatcher) that maps from $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ to itself have fixed point.

What can I say about the current question?

Comment: Do you know the Lefschetz fixed point theorem?  If so, think rational coefficients.

Comment: No I do not know that theorem. Will knowing the statement help me prove the question?

Comment: Yes - how did you finish the exercise in Hatcher?  I would have used Lefschetz...

Comment: For just $\mathbb{R}P^{2n}$ case, I can show maps from $S^{2n}$ to itself has the property that there is some x for which either f(x)=x or f(x)=-x using degree arguments.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  Lefschetz (see wikipedia) works great in this case because $\mathbb{R}P^{2k}$ has the rational cohomology of a point.  If you don't know cohomology groups, I'm unsure how to provide an answer to the question.

Comment: I do know Cohomology. Thanks for directing me towards Lefschetz fixed point theorem. I will read it ASAP.